# Stretch and rotate particular part of SVG image

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, svg, scale

I'm making a web interactive test for musicians, and got stuck up on, well, interactiveness.

Users are supposed to move notes on a stave and adjust them. 
SVG pathes are rendered as notes, with a separate parent div container for each note. Parent div is dragged on to the stave, and then can be resized ( I'm using jQuery UI for this, with option "handles" set to "e", so div can be resized only to the right). After this point I can not figure out how to correctly resize the SVG note inside it, because what needed to be resized, is not the whole SVG, but just one part.

SVGs look like this:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="24" height="32" viewBox="0 0 24 32" class="svgnote" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <path d="M0 23.703q0-0.922 0.672-1.797 0.313-0.344 0.766-0.711t1-0.727q0.531-0.25   1.031-0.359t0.953-0.109q0.953 0 1.688 0.531v-17.344h13.578v18.797q0 0.953-0.641 1.781-0.641 0.875-1.703 1.352t-2.047 0.477q-0.859 0-1.563-0.516t-0.703-1.375q0-0.984 0.703-1.797 0.609-0.797 1.719-1.438 0.578-0.25 1.055-0.359t0.93-0.109q0.969 0 1.703 0.531v-15.188h-12.484v16.641q0 0.953-0.641 1.781-0.641 0.875-1.695 1.352t-2.055 0.477q-0.891 0-1.594-0.516-0.672-0.516-0.672-1.375z"></path>
</svg>
```

[Picture example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVctv.png)
I added a picture, where above red figure

1. it's an initial state of a note;
2. upper red arrow is pointing out on a line, which is the only part of svg that needs to stretch out to the right.
   lower red arrows aside -- the note should (somehow?) be rotated up and down, to make 3rd state possible
3. is what final state of note I'm looking for.

What I have done:
except excessive googling, not much. I tried to set "width" of SVG image to "100%" of the parent div, and add preserveAspectRatio="none", but all I got is ugly stretched note.
As for rotation I do not have even a single idea from what should I start.
I'd be eternally grateful if someone point out for what should I google, or maybe a library should I use. I'm sensing a solution to this is close somewhere, I'm just missing it because of my very limited experience in the field.
Thank you all.

Comment: preserveAspectRatio does nothing without a viewBox

Comment: You need 3 `<path...` for this to work. Standalone note x2 and the connecting bar. Don't try stretching, looks real bad. Instead use javascript to move the note(s) and update connecting bar.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a 10mins hack. Connecting bar needs more work but the gist is use a collection of `<symbol>`for your musical notation and a better path (eg: polygon?) for the connecting bar.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  
  <symbol id="note-1" viewBox="0 0 313 340">
<g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="matrix(-1,0,0,-1,313,340)" id="g11029">
    <path d="M 303.13715,299.65106 C 299.74131,301.47103 297.93187,304.76561 299.04493,307.24402 C 300.23219,309.88766 304.31194,310.63374 308.15151,308.90939 C 311.99107,307.18503 314.14367,303.63999 312.95641,300.99636 C 311.76914,298.35272 307.6894,297.60664 303.84983,299.33099 C 303.60986,299.43876 303.36355,299.52973 303.13715,299.65106 z " style="opacity:0.9;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.2;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1" id="path11031"/>
    <path d="M 299.50465,305.98445 L 299.50465,339.57202" style="fill:none;fill-opacity:0.75;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.5;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1" id="path11033"/>
  </g> 
  </symbol>
  
  <g class="first" transform="translate(0,20)">
    <use xlink:href="#note-1" />
  </g>
  <g class="second" transform="translate(30,10)">
    <use xlink:href="#note-1" />
  </g>
  <path stroke-width="4" stroke="black" d="M87,20 L117,10"></path>
  
  
</svg>
```